# In the Italo high-speed train, what is the difference between club seat and "salotto"?

Tags: trains, tickets, italy, high-speed-rail

While booking a Milan to Naples ticket on the Italo high-speed train, I noticed some nice fares. Even the highest class, "Club Executive", has seats priced at €49 for a full fare on this stretch.

On the side, there is a "Salotto" option, which seems to be the same seat but in an enclosed compartment. Maybe there is some additional service, but there is something not clear. And it costs €200.

How can the price of the seat in "Salotto" be four times as much the price of an identical seat in the same class with the same ticket flexibility? Some less flexibly-priced regular Club seats are worth €29.

Does the high price justify special service, or is it simply that buying a single "Salotto" ticket gets all four seats in the compartment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salotto price is for the whole lounge, up to max 4 travellers (make a sample booking for 1/2/3/4 and you will see).

A [description of the comfort/service included can be found with Italo.](http://www.italotreno.it/en/the-train) Some excerpts for Club Executive:

- > either an “open space” area with wide personal spaces and comfortable Frau leather seats, or 2 lounges, equipped with personal wardrobes, which can be reserved en bloc for max 4 passengers.
- > We will be glad to welcome you at the platform and assist you when placing your luggage in either your coach secure area or in the practical and refined wardrobes reserved for our lounge guests. Once on board, you will be offered a nice espresso coffee and a selection of bakery or pastry products and hot and cold beverages.

Personally I'd say Club Executive is aligned with business class on planes, and Comfort or even Smart class are perfectly fine when promotional offers are no longer available.